# How to change UI Text Color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

My script works on on 3D GameObject but not on a `Text` component. How can I make it work on a Text? I would appreciate for you help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Colors : MonoBehaviour

{
public float timer = 0.0f;
Renderer rd;

void Start()
{
    rd = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}


void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= 2.0f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
    {
        // pick a random color
        Color newColor = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
        // apply it on current object's material
        rd.material.color = newColor;

        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question - please edit it so it actually contains question ("please help" is *not* a question).

Comment: you can NOT use Update() in this way.  Simply use **Invoke** to make a timer. It's easy.

Comment: Could you show me. I'm newbie of programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For UI Text, you use `Text.color` not `Renderer.material.color`. `Renderer` is used for 3D Objects with `Mesh Renderer` attached to them. Make sure to attach this to a GameObject with a `Text` Component attached to it or you will get an error.

```
public float timer = 0.0f;
Text txt;

void Start()
{
    txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
}


void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= 2.0f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
    {
        // pick a random color
        Color newColor = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
        // apply it on current object's material
        txt.color = newColor;

        timer = 0;
    }
}
```